# How to handle User Roles in Silex?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, silex

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    .
    .
    .
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.5.4",
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "symfony/security": "^3.1",
    "symfony/security-csrf": "^3.1",
    "twig/twig": "^1.24",
    .
    .
    .
},
```

I am using Doctrin ORM and I am unable to get security context to work in Silex:

**MyNameSpace\Model\UserProvider** (*Simplified*)

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $app;
    public function __construct(Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }
    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        $user = $this->app['em']->getRepository('MyNameSpace\Model\User')
            ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
        return $user;
    }
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'MyNameSpace\Model\User';
    }
}
```

**MyNameSpace\Model\User.php** (*Simplified*)

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as OR

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="array")
    */
    protected $roles;
    public function getRoles() {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        return array_unique($roles);
    }
    public function setRoles(array $newRoles) {
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
        foreach ($newRoles as $role) {
            $roles = $this->addRole($roles, $role);
        }
        return $this->roles;
    }
    public function addRole($roles, $role) {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        if ($role === 'ROLE_USER') {
            return;
        }
        if (!$this->hasRole($roles, $role)) {
            $roles[] = $role;
            return $roles;
        }
    }
    public function hasRole($roles, $role) {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $roles, true);
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->email,
            $this->roles,
            $this->enabled,
            $this->accountNonLocked,
            $this->accountNonExpired,
            $this->credentialsNonExpired
        ));
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->email,
            $this->roles,
            $this->enabled,
            $this->accountNonLocked,
            $this->accountNonExpired,
            $this->credentialsNonExpired
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

**roles field in user table in MySQL database:**

(`ROLE_USER` is always added through `MyNameSpace\Model\User:getRoles` method)

```
a:1:{i:0;s:11:"ROLE_CLIENT";}
```

**SecurityServiceProvider:**

```
$app->register(new Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'users' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/users/.*$',
            'anonymous' => false,
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/login',
                'check_path' => '/users/login_check',
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/users/logout',
                'invalidate_session' => true,
            ),
            'users' => function() use($app){
                return new UserProvider($app);
            },
        ),
    ),
    'security.role_hierarchy' => array(
        'ROLE_USER' => array(),
        'ROLE_CLIENT' => array('ROLE_USER'),
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        array('^/.+$', ''),
        array('^/login', ''),
        array('^/register', ''),
        array('^/users/.*$', 'ROLE_USER'),
    ),
));
```

It seams the user gets authenticated, as if I submit wrong credentials it will alert me with:

> Bad credentials.

but with right credentials, the `token` is null:

```
$app->get("/", function() use($app){
    $token = $app['security.token_storage']->getToken();
    if (null !== $token){
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $username = $user->getUsername();

        return $app['twig']->render('page.html.twig', array(
                'user' => $username
            )
        );
    }else{
        return $app['twig']->render('base.html.twig');
    }
});
```

The result is always `base.html.twig`.

## Notes

- Silex documentation does not use Doctrine ORM and stores Roles as comma separated string in database like:

  ```
    ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_ADMIN
  ```
- I am storing it using a serialized array:

  ```
    a:2:{i:0;s:11:"ROLE_CLIENT";i:1;s:10;"ROLE_ADMIN";}
  ```

and I do not know if this is the cause. Also I tried to store Roles as an array without success.